# RxJS 6 buffer with debounce as closingNotifier

Tags: javascript, buffer, rxjs6, debouncing

How should I implement my **Observables** to get the following behavior in **RxJS 6**?

[RxMarble diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l981g.png)

**Description:**
I'm trying to create a buffer[1] of incoming Observable[0] values, that buffers out after a debounce[2] time of the same Observable[0].

This is what I've got for now:

```
const Observable = rxjs.Observable;
const buffer = rxjs.operators.buffer;
const debounceTime = rxjs.operators.debounceTime;

const DEBOUNCE_TIME_SPAN = 2000;
let $observableObserver = null;

// Custom cold observable.
const $observable = Observable.create((observer) => {
  // Exposed observer
  $observableObserver = observer;
  // Manual entries
  observer.next(0);
});

// Debounce time observable (OK)
const $debouncedObservable = $observable
  .pipe(debounceTime(DEBOUNCE_TIME_SPAN));

// Buffered observable (THIS DOES NOT WORK)
const $bufferObservable = $debouncedObservable
  .pipe(buffer($observable));

// So this doesn't print something correct.
$bufferObservable.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(v),
});
```